# Are python tuples modifiable?

Tags: python

I'm reading in and parsing some data.  Basically, the data is a bunch of integers and strings, so I can't use just a list to store the data.  There's a set number of items that will be in each set of data, but sometimes some are missing.  Here is what I have.

```
users = [] # list of objects I'll be creating

# this all gets looped.  snipped for brevity
data = "id", "gender", -1 # my main tuple that I will create my object with
words = line.split()
index = 0
data[0] = words[index]
index += 1
if words[index] == "m" or words[index] == "f":
    data[1] = words[index]
    index += 1
else:
    data[1] = "missing"

if words[index].isdigit():
    data[2] = words[index]
    index += 1

users.append(User(data))
```

The problem is you can't seem to be able to assign directly to tuples (such as `data[1] = "missing"`), so how should this be assigned in a pythonic manner?

Comment: "Basically, the data is a bunch of integers and strings, so I can't use just a list to store the data."  Care to unpack that?

Comment: Tuples are immutable, but if you need to store things as a tuple, you can always create it as a list first, and then call `tuple(list)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: modify Tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353589/python-modify-tuple)

Comment: Class instances are basically glorified tuples anyway ;)

Comment: Note that `if words[index] == 'm' or words[index] == 'f':` is also not pythonic.  Try `if words[index] in ('m', 'f'):` instead.  You also seem to be incrementing your index a lot.  You could probably do it less, or better, use a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python tuples are immutable. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> Tuples, like strings, are immutable: it is not possible to assign to the individual items of a tuple (you can simulate much of the same effect with slicing and concatenation, though). It is also possible to create tuples which contain mutable objects, such as lists.

That's the principal thing that sets them apart from lists. Which leads nicely on to one possible solution: use a list in place of the tuple:

```
data = ["id", "gender", -1]
```

Comment: Yikes.  I had no idea you could throw different types into a single list.  Sorry for the easy question, and thanks!

Comment: No need to apologise. Things are only easy once you've learnt them!

Comment: "their items cannot be modified" is false. Tuples can contain mutable objects e.g., `tup = ([],); tup[0].append(1)` you just can't assign to individual items e.g., `tup[0] = "XXX won't work"`. The snippet from the docs explicitly mentions both points.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Well, I didn't mean it that way. I've removed my explanation now and let the docs speak for themselves.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct, tuples are immutable. However, you can put any different types into a python list.

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append("a")
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a.append(False)
>>> print a
['a', 1, False]
```

Comment: -1.  Humorous.  But unhelpful.  The crux of the question is the last sentence: "The problem is you can't seem to be able to assign directly to tuples (such as `data[1] = "missing"`), so how should this be assigned in a pythonic manner?"

Comment: When I downvoted, your answer was just "That's correct, tuples are immutable."  Unfortunately, it looks like you were editing your question at the same time.  I would remove my downvote in light of your edit but my vote is locked in.  Sorry.  If you edit your question again, ping me in the comments and I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a tuple (though as others have said, a list should work fine), just store your data to temp variables and create the tuple from scratch with the temps at the end of the loop instead of at the beginning with dummy values.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like the first field "id" will never be missing.
Let's assume you really want a tuple for passing to your User class.

You could do your checks first and then assign the totality of the result to your tuple...

```
if words[1] in "mf":
    data=tuple(words[i] for i in range(0,3))
else:
    data=words[0],"missing",words[2]
```

You should however be careful that the fields (if they exist) that follow are split correctly, otherwise field meaning will get mixed up.