# Can't edit a tuple from inside a function

Tags: python, tuples

I am programming an application in python. Here is the function:

```
def aircraftListBoxRefresh():
    sqlConnect=sqlite3.connect("fglconfdb")
    sqlCursor=sqlConnect.cursor()
    sqlCursor.execute("SELECT fgAircraftDir FROM fglconfig")
    adl=sqlCursor.fetchall()
    global aircraftDirectories
    for x in adl:
        aircraftDirectories=aircraftDirectories+(x,)
```

---

I put `print(aircraftDirectories)` to test whether the value changes. It changes in side the function. But outside the function it is null.

I am trying to access the value with this:

```
aircraftDirectories=()
aircraftDir=StringVar(value=aircraftDirectories)
aircraftListBox=Listbox(mainframe,height=7,width=100,listvariable=aircraftDir)
aircraftListBox.place(x=170,y=170)
```

But I can't. 
Any help greatly appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: Related: [Are python tuples modifiable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710093/are-python-tuples-modifiable)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Changing what you've bound a local variable won't do anything, though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify tuples anywhere, inside a function or outside, they're immutable.   Maybe you want lists:

```
def aircraftListBoxRefresh():
    sqlConnect=sqlite3.connect("fglconfdb")
    sqlCursor=sqlConnect.cursor()
    sqlCursor.execute("SELECT fgAircraftDir FROM fglconfig")
    adl=sqlCursor.fetchall()
    for x in adl:
        aircraftDirectories.append(x)

aircraftDirectories=[]
aircraftDir=StringVar(value=aircraftDirectories)
aircraftListBox=Listbox(mainframe,height=7,width=100,listvariable=aircraftDir)
aircraftListBox.place(x=170,y=170)
```

With this approach, since you're modifying the list and not re-assigning to the variable, you don't need `global`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a tuple, but you can replace it. In this example M[] is a list of tuples, each tuple contains two numbers. I want to replace the first number of a tuple to 0, but keep the second number.

```
M[j] = (0, M[j][1])
```